# Unable to completely remove Docker from Centos

Tags: docker, centos7

I tried literally all advices and hints, but still can not uninstall Docker completely from Centos 7. When I run this command:

```
$ yum remove docker-ce
```

And after that run this command:

```
$ docker ps
```

I still get this notorious alert:

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

I also tried to remove all files and repositories related to Docker:

```
$ rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

I tried many other remove commands, but still `docker ps` returns me that nasty alert. So, is there a way to completely erase Docker from Centos?

Comment: Can you try solution at https://askubuntu.com/questions/935569/how-to-completely-uninstall-docker Looks like it has multiple packages

Comment: @Omkar Nath Singh. That solution relates to Ubuntu. But I need to remove Docker from Centos

Comment: I know, but the problem is same. You can try yum remove doker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce

Comment: It seems additional packages are present.

Comment: I tried your command. But still `docker ps` returns an alert

Comment: try `yum remove docker docker-client docker-client-latest docker-common docker-latest docker-latest-logrotate docker-logrotate docker-engine`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wrote years ago an installation program that removes old Dockers. These are from the latest version of that program. Like you see Docker has changed many times, thus you may try several removes.

ORIGINAL SOURCES USED FOR THESE COMMANDS:

1. https://docs.master.dockerproject.org/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#os-requirements
2. https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ee/rhel/

Removing old docker and docker-engine installations

```
yum remove -y docker \
    docker-client \
    docker-client-latest \
    docker-common \
    docker-latest \
    docker-latest-logrotate \
    docker-logrotate \
    docker-selinux \
    docker-engine-selinux \
    docker-engine
```

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#uninstall-docker-ce

Removing Community Edition (docker-ce) installations

```
yum remove -y docker-ce
rm -rd /var/lib/docker
```

DOCKER-EE (UPDATED 2019-02-19)

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ee/centos/#uninstall-docker-ee

Removing Enterprise Edition (docker-ee) installations"
Uninstall the Docker EE package:
    yum remove -y docker-ee

Delete all images, containers, and volumes 
(because these are not automatically removed from your host):

```
rm -rd /var/lib/docker  2>/dev/null
```

Delete other Docker related resources:

```
rm -rf /run/docker
rm -rf /var/run/docker
rm -rf /etc/docker
```

If desired, remove the devicemapper thin pool and reformat the block devices
that were part of it.

You have to delete any edited configuration files manually.